# How to draw a circle on to panel in java swing

Tags: java, swing, graphics, draw, geometry

I am trying to draw a circle for a game I am making for a class.

This is my code:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    // Assume x, y, and diameter are instance variables.
    Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(50, 50, 150, 150);
}
```

However, when I run the code, it is not seen (My frame is 300 by 300)

Comment: Well you don't show the frame or how the panel is added to the frame. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for working examples you can download and customize. If you need more help then post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Did you add the component to the frame? Maybe you should try also adding `g2d.setColor(Color.RED);` and `g2d.fill(circle);` to your `paintComponent` method